# Facing issue to use spark inside python function

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub

Im reading data from event hub through databricks. the data from event hub is json messages.Im using a foreach funtion to save the json message to adls. Im getting error as below can anyone help ?
[image]

and process_row is a simple functions which takes json message and removes unnecessary keys saves that to adls. Can anyone help me how to use spark in this function.

```
def process_row(row):
    a = json.loads(row['newBody'])
    final_df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `spark` variable inside `process_row`. You could try:

```
df.writeStream.foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
  // Transform and write batchDF
  batchDF.select($"newBody").write() # write into anywhere you want
}.start()
```

Comment: newBody is a dictionary object , which contains around 100 keys. So from this object i need to keep only 10 keys and make a dataframe from dict with 10 keys and write it to adls. this is my requirement. DO you have any idea how i can do this ?